# Test passes but Coverage does not update - Jest Enzyme - React JS

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following test and is passing at the moment. When i run npm test --coverage, the coverage still the same

Here is the test file:

```js
it('should call  button click', () => {
  baseProps.onClick.mockClear();
  baseProps.closeModal.mockClear();

  wrapper.setState({
    INITIAL_STATE: {}
  });

  wrapper.find('#BatchUpdate-testClick').simulate('click');
  expect(baseProps.closeModal).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Here is the code:

```
<div className='security-search-wrapper-modal'>
   <div className='fullmodal'> 
   <div className='fullmodal_title'>Batch Update</div>
   <div title="Close Window" className="add-custom-field-close" 
   id='BatchUpdate-testClick' onClick={() => {this.closeModal()}}> 
   <FontAwesome name='xbutton' className='fa-times' /></div>
```

Goal: Test coverage increase since the test is passing at the moment